# Is there any function to call after activity load on screen?

Tags: android

Is there any function to call after activity load on screen ? I need to show AlertDialog in some occasions and if I put that in onResume it looks strange, dialog is already visible and I want to user see when AlertDialog popup.

Comment: Maybe `onResume()` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you want onWindowFocusChanged().  You are going to want to add some extra logic to this method call though because it will be called anytime the window gains or loses focus.  Not sure what your use-case is but could just add a global boolean to see if it was the first call or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for this
place below code in onCreate() methode

```
Handler handler =  new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

and implement the runnable as

```
    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
}
};
```

in the postDelayed(runnable,decide your time) this will help you.
i hope i give you answer.

Comment: 5 sec is too much. you can try with a lesser value too 200ms.